# Image comparison using Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gesture-recognition, pattern-recognition, image-recognition

i am planning to create an application to compare pill images if they were the same.
Is there any source that i could use that detects colors, shape, size of the pill in the picture and compre if that picture is the same with the other picture of the same pill?

Regards,
ZaldzBgz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know a good library for computer vision, not sure if it can help you. You can look at: [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/). It worked with iPhone

Comment: OpenCV is probably the best library to manipulate images regarding computer vision, and pattern/image recognition. The library enables you to do simple image operations and provides methods that allow you to build advanced applications such as your own surveillance system program. You should definitely check out this library, as there is also a lot of examples and documentation on the web.